# How to pass C# dictionary into typescript Map

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

How can I pass correctly C# dictionary into typescript Map.

```
[HttpGet("reportsUsage")]
    public IActionResult GetReportsUsage()
    {
        //var reportsUsage = _statService.GetReportsUsage();

        IDictionary<int, int> test = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        test.Add(1, 20);
        test.Add(2, 30);
        test.Add(3, 40);
        test.Add(4, 50);
        test.Add(5, 70);
        test.Add(6, 60);
        test.Add(7, 90);
        test.Add(8, 30);

        return Ok(test);
        //return Ok(reportsUsage );
    }
```

In angular:

```
getReportsUsage() {
return this.http.get<Map<number, number>>(`${environment.apiUrl}/stats/reportsUsage`, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }),
  withCredentials: true
});
}

reportsUsage = new Map<number, number>();

this.statsService.getReportsUsage().subscribe(data => {
    this.reportsUsage = data;
    
    //1
    console.log(this.reportsUsage);
    //2
    console.log(this.reportsUsage.values());
    //3
    console.log(typeof(this.reportsUsage));
};
```

Results:

1

> {1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 50, 5: 70, 6: 60, 7: 90, 8: 30}

2

> ERROR TypeError: this.reportsUsage.values is not a function

3

> object

So the data type change from Dictionary into object, I have tried to convert it with the below but still not working:

```
console.log(new Map(this.reportsUsage));
```

> TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that C# is very relevant here, other than the fact that what comes over the wire is a JSON object like this:

```
const data: Record<number, number> = 
  { 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 50, 5: 70, 6: 60, 7: 90, 8: 30 };
```

This is not already a [JavaScript `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but a plain JSON object.  So the right type to use is probably `Record<number, number>` where I'm using the [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to say "an object with numeric keys and numeric values".

So when you call your `http.get` you should specify `Record<number, number>` instead of `Map<number, number>`:

```
this.http.get<Record<number, number>>(...)
```

---

If you want to convert that into a `Map`, you need to call [the `Map` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) with an appropriately iterable argument (such as an array) of key-value [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  And since JSON objects always have `string` keys and not actual `number`s, you need to convert to numbers yourself if you want the resulting map to be `Map<number, number>` instead of `Map<string, number>`:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [+k, v]));
// const map: Map<number, number>
```

This is using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert the JavaScript object into an array of such entry tuples, and we are [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) these entries so that the keys are numbers.

Let's make sure it works:

```
console.log(map.get(3)?.toFixed(2)) // "40.00"
```

Looks good.
[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDASgU1AJzgHjAFcBbAI0xwBoZjzKA+GAXhgG8YBGNAJgAYaPNAGYBMYWgAsYyWgCsYuWgDsYgGxo1Y5WgCcYgBwi+MAL4BuAFChIsEggAOLWpgDuMALKOAFAHkyAFbYUAB0mGBQOACWmBDeiMgAlCH2Dt7eANoA1jQAbgC6iSxMGQDUOTAFiYlWAPS1MDbQMKloXg6EpBTUtF2M1uAQIAA2mCHDIADm3qkhk5hQ3sKJAPwhUCAAYlEAHphw3jzVMPUwAETSIXx8Z0A)

Answer (score 1):

1- if you want to create a map out of reportsUsage:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(this.reportsUsage));
console.log(map.get("1")); // prints 20
```

2- if you want an array with the values only:

```
const arrayOfValues = Object.values(this.reportsUsage)
```